# View outlines(bookmarks) of a pdf

Tags: c#, pdfsharp

I created a PDF file with library PDFsharp with this [code](http://www.pdfsharp.net/wiki/Bookmarks-sample.ashx). I open the file with Adobe Reader and the bookmarks are created. Then I created another program when I read this created PDF file and I want to view my bookmarks but the `Outlines` collection `Count` is 0 and `HasOutline` is false. Is it a bug?
Do you have tried to display the bookmarks of a PDF?

Sorry for my English

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a known limitation that the Outlines collection remains empty when you open an existing document.

You can access the outlines using GetObject() if you have to.

See also:
http://forum.pdfsharp.net/viewtopic.php?p=705#p705
http://forum.pdfsharp.net/viewtopic.php?p=1008#p1008

Comment: Thanks.Sorry that i did not search better.